# How to grab specifically what I need using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website and pull info from multiple spots on the site, and the html looks like this:

```
<div class="Item-Details">
    <p class="Product-title">
        <a href="/link_i_need">
            text here that i need to grab
            more text here that i would like to grab
        </a>
    </p>
```

I am using this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
mydivs = soup.findAll("p", {"class": "product-title"})
for div in mydivs:
    print(div)
```

But it returns this:

```
<p class="product-title">
<a href="/info">line 1 description as well as line 2 description with no break</a>
</p>
```

I need to return the href portion in quotes, as well as both lines separately.  I have tried using these but neither works:

```
print(div.get('href'))
print(div.find('a'))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the `div` tag, you can get the `href` attribute of the `a` tag by doing this: `div.find("a")['href']`. So for your code, it'd look like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
mydivs = soup.findAll("p", {"class": "product-title"})
for div in mydivs:
    print(div.find("a")['href'])
```

Note that this will error out if any of the elements do not have a `href` attribute.

For the text inside, you can use the `.text` property, like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
mydivs = soup.findAll("p", {"class": "product-title"})
for div in mydivs:
    print(div.find("a").text)
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! This is exactly what i needed. I was just missing a couple little parts at the end.  Greatly Appreciated!!!

Comment: So i am running into a problem with one link that does not have an href tag, like you mentioned, and now it is erroring out.  How can I add an if-else statement, so that IF the href tag exists, then get it and if not, do something else?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out using a try, except (AttributeError).

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, you're missing the closing tag `</div>`. Then, you have a typo. It's `"Product-title"` not `"product-title"`. Finally, looping over your divs doesn't get you any closer to your desired output.

So, assuming your `HTML` looks like this:

```
sample = """
<div class="Item-Details">
    <p class="Product-title">
        <a href="/link_i_need">
            text here that i need to grab
            more text here that i would like to grab
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
"""
```

You could try this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(sample, "html.parser").find_all("p", {"class": "Product-title"})
for stuff in soup:
    print(f"{stuff.find('a').get('href')}\n{stuff.find('a').getText(strip=True)}")
```

To get this:

```
/link_i_need
text here that i need to grab
            more text here that i would like to grab
```

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, the html looks like what you added, I just wrote it up because I could not figure out how to copy/paste from my inspector in chrome. This solves my question, and your help is greatly appreciated!